# How to define linear mappings on a vector space spanned by abstract symbols?

Tags: linear-algebra, symbolic

Say I have an infinite dimensional vector space $V$ with basis consists of abstract symbols  $\{ a_j \}^\infty_{j=0}$, and consider a linear function $f$ on $V$ defined by its action on the basis elements, say $f[a_j]=j *a_{j}+j^2 * a_{j+1}, \forall j\geq 0$. I want to implement this function $f$ in mathematica that computes $f$ for any finite linear combination of $\{a_j\}^\infty_{j=0}$ (i.e. any vector in $V$). Sure I can input $f[a_j]$ into the definition of $f$, but how could I let mathematica know that $f$ is a linear function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linearity is defined as `f[x_+y_]= f[x]+f[y]` and `f[lam x_] = lam f[x]`, where `lam` is a scalar. Further, do not use subscripted variables, use indexed ones instead. Therefore:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[a[j_]] := j  a[j] + j^2 a[j + 1];
f[x_ + y_] := f[x] + f[y];
f[lam_?NumericQ  x_] := lam f[x]
```

We can now calculate e.g. the image of some vector `a[0] + a[1] + 2 a[2]`:

```
f[a[0] + a[1] + 2 a1[2]]
%% // Simplify

a[1] + a[2] + 2 (2 a[2] + 4 a[3])

a[1] + 5 a[2] + 8 a[3]
```